# how to save array variables (json array)(reddit oauth) into database mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, oauth

I have a code to get user details from `reddit` using `oauth` :

```
$response = $client->fetch("https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me.json");
```

When I print the result like :

```
print_r($response);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
[result] => Array
    (
        [is_employee] => 
        [name] => Care_ishabell
        [created] => 1458655844
        [hide_from_robots] => 
        [is_suspended] => 
        [created_utc] => 1458627044
        [link_karma] => 1
        [in_beta] => 
        [comment_karma] => 0
        [over_18] => 
        [is_gold] => 
        [is_mod] => 
        [id] => wklr5
        [gold_expiration] => 
        [inbox_count] => 1
        [has_verified_email] => 
        [gold_creddits] => 0
        [suspension_expiration_utc] => 
    )

[code] => 200
[content_type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
)
```

Now I want to store values in variables to insert into database.
But when I try to store value in variables using :

```
$username = $response->result->name;
```

and echo it. Then it displays error :

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>       G:\XAMPP\htdocs\a\redditlogin\index.php on line 45
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>       G:\XAMPP\htdocs\a\redditlogin\index.php on line 45.

So help me to store values in variables, so that I can store them in database.

Comment: This is an array not object use `$response['result']['name']`

Comment: @Saty.....it works....thanks.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print_r($response);` contain array of array, So instead of `$response->result->name;` use `$response['result']['name']`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, @saty is right, also to answer the question in your subject, to store this in a database, just use `json_encode` function which will turn this array into a JSON string that you can save in you database.

Comment: how did this deserve a nevative vote ? any explanation please ? thanks